# Nested flexboxes don't display properly in old Android browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an annoying issue with a webpage I need to create that will load on Android 4.4.2's browser (Webkit). The page layout

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.m-5 {
 margin: 5px;
}

div {
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 clear:none;
 background-color: rgba(55, 55, 255, .2);
}

/*
    Display
*/

.d-flex {
    display: flex !important;
}

.d-inline-flex {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}

.d-none {
    display: none !important;
}

/*
    Direction
*/

.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row !important;
}

.flex-row-reverse {
    flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column !important;
}

.flex-column-reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}

/*
    Justify Content
*/

.justify-content-start {
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.justify-content-end {
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
}

.justify-content-between {
    justify-content: space-between !important;
}

.justify-content-around {
    justify-content: space-around !important;
}

/*
    Align Items
*/

.align-items-start {
    align-items: flex-start !important;
}

.align-items-end {
    align-items: flex-end !important;
}

.align-items-center {
    align-items: center !important;
}

.align-items-baseline {
    align-items: baseline !important;
}

.align-items-stretch {
    align-items: stretch !important;
}

/*
    Align Self
*/

.align-self-start {
    align-self: flex-start !important;
}

.align-self-end {
    align-self: flex-end !important;
}

.align-self-center {
    align-self: center !important;
}

.align-self-baseline {
    align-self: baseline !important;
}

.align-self-stretch {
    align-self: stretch !important;
}

/*
    Align Content
*/

.align-content-start {
    align-content: flex-start !important;
}

.align-content-end {
    align-content: flex-end !important;
}

.align-content-center {
    align-content: center !important;
}

.align-content-around {
    align-content: space-around !important;
}

.align-content-stretch {
    align-content: stretch !important;
}

/*
    Wrap
*/

.flex-nowrap {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.flex-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.flex-wrap-reverse {
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse !important;
}

/*
    Flex options
*/

.flex-grow {
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
}

.flex-shrink {
    flex-shrink: 1 !important;
}

.flex-basis-12 {
    flex-basis: 100% !important;
}

.flex-basis-11 {
    flex-basis: calc((11/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-10 {
    flex-basis: calc((10/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-9 {
    flex-basis: calc((9/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-8 {
    flex-basis: calc((8/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-7 {
    flex-basis: calc((7/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-6 {
    flex-basis: calc((6/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-5 {
    flex-basis: calc((5/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-4 {
    flex-basis: calc((4/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-3 {
    flex-basis: calc((3/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-2 {
    flex-basis: calc((2/12) * 100%) !important;
}
.flex-basis-1 {
    flex-basis: calc((1/12) * 100%) !important;
}

.flex-basis-auto {
    flex-basis: auto !important;
}

/*
    Size
*/

.w-100 {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.h-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
}

::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="m-5 flex-basis-1 d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-3"></div>
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-3" style="background-color: transparent"></div>
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-3"></div>
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-3" style="background-color: transparent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-5 flex-basis-11 d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-7 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="m-5 flex-basis-9"></div>
    <div class="m-5 flex-basis-3 d-flex flex-row">
     <div class="m-5 flex-basis-4"></div>
     <div class="m-5 flex-basis-4"></div>
     <div class="m-5 flex-basis-4"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="m-5 flex-basis-5 d-flex flex-column"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

On your browser this (should) be laid out properly, but on Android 4 the the left panel doesn't display it's top and bottom items. If I change the direction of the left panel to row, the items display as expected, but obviously I can't have it as a row. If I remove the flex-basis for both children of the left panel and add flex-grow, it also displays as expected, 50% each panel.

It seems to be a bug with nested flex rows and columns, but I cannot figure out a workaround for this.

Comment: Why do you have `div { float: left; clear: none }`?

Comment: That was left over from some other testing without using flexbox, but I've just checked and confirmed that without that, it still doesn't display properly.